# Numpy: creating batch of numpy arrays within another numpy array (reshaping)

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, indexing

I have a numpy array `batch` of shape `(32,5)`. Each element of the batch consists of a numpy array `batch_elem = [s,_,_,_,_]`  where  `s = [img,val1,val2]` is a 3-dimensional numpy array and `_` are simply scalar values.
`img` is an image (numpy array) with dimensions `(84,84,3)`

I would like to create a numpy array with the shape `(32,84,84,3)`. Basically I want to extract the image information within each `batch` and transform it into a 4-dimensional array.

I tried the following:

```
b = np.vstack(batch[:,0]) #this yields a b with shape (32,3), type: <class 'numpy.ndarray'>
```

Now I would like to access the images (first index in second dimension)

```
img_batch = b[:,0] # this returns an array of shape (32,), type: <class 'numpy.ndarray'>
```

How can I best access the image data and get a shape `(32,84,84,3)`?

Note:

```
 s = b[0] #first s of the 32 in batch: shape (3,) , type: <class 'numpy.ndarray'>
```

Edit:

This should be a minimal example:

```
img = np.zeros([5,5,3])
s = np.array([img,1,1])
batch_elem = np.array([s,1,1,1,1])
batch = np.array([batch_elem for _ in range(32)])
```

Comment: `img_batch=np.array([a[i, 0] for i in range(a.shape[0])])` should work

Comment: Is ```a[0,0]``` a list?

Comment: `np.array([a[i,0][0] for i in range(a.shape[0])])` works. But is there a way without list comprehensions?

Comment: `a[0,0]` is `<class 'numpy.ndarray'>`

Comment: It would be nice if you could construct a minimal example of ```a``` , preferably with a few less dimensions and provide it for us.  At least the process you used to construct the minimal example.

Comment: So ```a[0,0][0]``` is an image you are interested in?

Comment: Yes  exactly. Basically its a numpy array  (image) within a numpy array (s) within a numpy array (a)

Comment: Couple of observations: (1) you have `a` within `a`? (2) maybe strip away `r` and `d` from the question? (since they are not really used / relevant - for the purpose of this question)

Comment: sorry  you're right i was lazy. I will edit it

Comment: Regarding the edited version, `batch` should be of shape `(32, 3)`, no?  (as we are talking in numpy array here. no lists. (unless `batch` is a list?)

Comment: It would help if you could clarify whether these are `list` or `numpy.array`: (1) `batch`, (2) `s`, (3) `img`. (wanted to triple check)

Comment: Hi I added a minimal example. I hope its correct. The actual construction is kind of convoluted..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming I understand the problem correctly, you can stack twice on the last axis.

`res = np.stack(np.stack(batch[:,0])[...,0])`

Comment: Wow this is pretty amazing. I was stuck for ages on this :). Looks good - it gives a shape of `(32, 5, 5, 3)`

Answer (score 1):

```
import numpy as np

# fabricate some data
batch = np.array((32, 1), dtype=object)
for i in range(len(batch)):
    batch[i] = [np.random.rand(84, 84, 3), None, None]

# select images
result = np.array([img for img, _, _ in batch])

# double check!
for i in range(len(batch)):
    assert np.all(result[i, :, :, :] == batch[i][0])
```

Comment: Thank you, I found that this works: `np.array([batch[i,0][0] for i in range(batch.shape[0])])`. I was looking for a solution without list comprehensions/loops. If that is possible